# Making a method for Hash

Tags: ruby

So I have a question of best practice in terms of extending functionality of common Ruby datatypes.

So Rails of course has a great method `pluralize` which takes a string and pluralizes it. What I'm particularly interested in is that you can call

```
"square".pluralize
```

and receive

```
=> "squares"
```

in return. What I want to do is a similar sort of thing -- except for a Hash. For the sake of this question, let's say I have a method `pluralize_each` which pluralizes each `key` and `value` of a hash.

```
def pluralize_each hash
  hash.each {|key,value| puts key.pluralize + "=>" + value.pluralize }
end
```

How can I manipulate this method so that I can call it on just a hash? 
For example, I want to be able to call

```
{"cat" => "dog"}.pluralize_each
#=> {"cats" => "dogs"}
```

(Let's forget that this particular method isn't fully functional right now, with nested hashes and such.)

Is there any way to do this except for extending the Hash class? I would think that there would be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a module:

```
module HashPluralize
  def pluralize
    each { |key,value| puts "#{key.pluralize} => #{value.pluralize}" }
  end
end

Hash.send(:include, HashPluralize)

# Usage example:
{'user' => 'product'}.pluralize
users => products
```

---

## EDIT: WHY?

@KL-7 legitimately asked a class edit vs module extension. This is my opinion:

If you are writing something organic, modules can be useful in order to optimize refactoring / code organization. Example:

```
module Pluralization

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send :include, Pluralization.const_get(klass.to_s)
  rescue TypeError
    raise NotImplementedError.new("A pluralization method for the #{klass}" +
            " class is not supported at the moment")
  end

  module Array
    def pluralize
      'array pluralization implementation'
    end
  end

  module Hash
    def pluralize
      'hash pluralization implementation'
    end
  end

end

Array.send :include, Pluralization
Hash.send :include, Pluralization

puts Array.new.pluralize
puts Hash.new.pluralize
```

This module permits you to define a clean way to define pluralizations for various classes; you could add a configuration, separate the pluralization methods in various files, etc.

Anyway, if you just want to add a `pluralize` method to Hash class, there is no problem editing the Hash class (just ensure you are not overriding another method, with a `method_defined?` check f.e.)

Comment: How is it better than re-opening the class?

Comment: @ProGNOMmers Aha! And so this is how I would make a gem to extend Hash functionality?

Comment: _Is there any way to do this except for extending the Hash class? I would think that there would be a way._ Did you read the question?

Comment: I think the first version of the question didn't include this requirement. Even if it did I think the question is not exactly about how to do the same thing in a different way, but how to make it in a better way. If OP wants to have this method in any Hash instance (without manually extending every instance he want to call the method on) I think your solution doesn't have any advantage. If there's one, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: @varatis, if you're going to put it into a gem, creating a subclass of `Hash` with this special pluralization functionality seems better to me. Otherwise, users of your gem will need not only install it, but also manually include this module into the core class (that is not very nice).

Comment: Here's why it's better than reopening the class: http://johnragan.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/safer-monkey-patching/

Comment: @rcrogers, that's a good argument, but I wouldn't bother creating a module if I do it inside a well defined place in my own app. But it's definitely a better solution for a gem, thanks for bringing that up. Btw, since 1.9 you can find the offending method even inside a reopened class with `Method#source_location`.

Comment: @KL-7 : I updated my answer. What do you think about? I'm interested about your opinion

Comment: @ProGNOMmers, interesting approach, thanks for sharing. I don't remember extending core classes in my apps too often, but when you write a gem, `core_ext` directory containing a separate file for every extended core class (and maybe a subdirectory, if you have lots of extensions for the same class) seems more common for me. See https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext for example.

Comment: IMHO it is a matter of how advanced is your need, how you want to organize your code, etc. Rails core extensions are static, Rails guys do not need to expose an API in order to choose which extensions load, neither complex abstractions, so they rightly keep their code simple. I saw the module approach in some gems, but sincerely I don't remember any of them in order to use as example :-/

Comment: @ProGNOMmers Question: if I <i>were</i> to make a gem using your module implementation, would I have to require the user of the gem to do `Array.send :include, Pluralization` each time they wanted to use the module's functionality? Excuse my ignorance if this is a stupid question...

Comment: @varatis if you make the `Array.send :include, Pluralization` call in your gem you are good to go

Comment: @ProGNOMmers Yup just tried it out yesterday, works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hash
  def pluralize_each
    each { |key,value| puts "#{key.pluralize} => #{value.pluralize}" }
  end
end
```

If you want to call your own method on a `Hash` instance I doubt there's a way other than re-opening the class.

Answer (score 0):

Making a sub-method of Hash is definitely the best way, given Ruby's object-oriented paradigm.  But if you wanted to make a global method for some reason, then there's two ways to check the argument class.

One is with "instance_of?" (which tests that the argument is of a specific class) or "kind_of?" (which allows sub-classes; generally a good idea).  So for example:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.kind_of? Hash
```

is true.

So you can check your arguments in this way.  Another option is "duck-typing" to see if the object acts like a hash, for example to see if it has a ".keys" method:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.respond_to? :keys
```

I'd stick with inserting methods into the Hash class, however:

```
class Hash
  def ...
  end
end
```

or define a sub-class of Hash and put the method there:

```
class Hash_with_plural < Hash
  def ...
  end
end
```

because it's much cleaner.